# How to get email addresses from distribution list in outlook using VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have written this excerpt of code to grab the email addresses of users from the to, cc and bcc lines when the email send button is clicked.

```
if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {      
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
            Outlook.Recipients myRecipients = mailItem.Recipients;
            foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in myRecipients)
            {  
                addresses.Add(recipient.Address);
            }
        }
```

The code does what I need it to do. However, if the user enters a distribution list in the to, cc or bcc lines my program is not able to read the email addresses from the distribution list. I am looking for a solution to either read email addresses from the distribution list or expand the distribution list.

Comment: Supposedly, the `recipient` has the Recipient.AddressEntry property, then you can access the AddressEntry.Members collection. Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba8aea47-fa3f-44ac-bda7-93b92505aacf/outlook-addin-how-to-know-members-of-distribution-group-in-mailitemrecipients?forum=vsto

Answer (score 1):

You can call `ResolveAll()` method of `Recipients` or `Resovle()` for each `Recipient`.
After resolving all addresses get `ExchangeDistributionList` object via `GetExchangeDistributionList()` which provides the method `GetMemberOfList()` which it its turn returns `AddressEntries` object.

Comment: Thanks for your input Hamlet. I am having trouble understanding which object calls the GetExchangeDistributionList() method.

Comment: The AddressEntry object has that method. The Outlook Object Model documentation is your friend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangedistributionlist?view=outlook-pia

Comment: Keep in mind that GetExchangeDistributionList is Exchange specific. It will not work with local DLs. Recipients.AddressEntry.Members collection will work in all cases.

Comment: `AddressEntry.Members` is deprecated.